# Developing Google Gadget on a Mac

Tags: macos, api, google-gadget

I have developed some Mac Widgets and want to port them to Google Gadgets. The technology is pretty similar (please disabuse me if this is not the case) but it looks like i need to download and use the Google Gadgets to speed things up which means i have to use Windows. Is there a way of running it on the Mac. Basecamp? Or is it easy enough to hand crank the gadget development? Or should i simply dust of a Windows machine?

I am using Snow Leopard and the Googls Gadgets for the Mac is only a way (it seems) of running the gadgets on the Mac not developing them.

Basecamp? Oops sorry meant Bootcamp and my fingers got mixed up.

Comment: What does Basecamp have to do with anything?

Comment: how about just parallels, if you thinking about runing windows on mac. http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/

what about http://desktop.google.com/mac/?

Comment: As mentioned do not need windows. THe documentation and textmate do it just fine.

Google do provide a tool, windows based, for visually creating the gadget but it is not much work to read the documentation, download some code and hack.

Easy to test as well as just load to a public URL and then add into yur own iGoogle to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of the API, Gadgets are XML files. You do not need Windows to create or edit these.